# How to highlight a selected text in UITextView . in epubreader app?

Tags: ios, uiwebview, uitextview, epub

Currently working on a epub reader project . viewing the page , highlighting the text , taking notes are working fine  using UIWebView. I want to change it from UIWEbview into UITextView with Paging Controller. If i do this , how would perform selecting text on that ? Currently am using Javacript . Will this javascript work on UITextView. ? Thanks in advance.